# Determine if vectors intersects in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors of strings. It is needed to determine if they are intersects (has one or more the same elements). For example:

```
["1" "2" "3"] ["11" "3" "44"] => true

["22" "33"] ["44" "55"] => false
```

What is the better way to do it?

Comment: the best way is to write a function that does that!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Don't worry about your question being initially down-voted, If you edit your answer to include some portion of the code you have tried and what the result was people will be more successful in writing answers that make sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clojure has a built in function for calculating set intersection. So you can simply check if the intersection is not empty:

```
main> (not (empty? (apply clojure.set/intersection
                          (map set
                               [["1" "2" "3"] 
                                ["11" "3" "44"]]))))
true
main> (not (empty? (apply clojure.set/intersection
                          (map set
                               [["22" "33"] 
                                ["44" "55"]]))))
false
```

Answer (score 3):

you could add first vector to a set, and then use `some` to check if some of the second vector's values is in this set:

```
user> (def v1 ["1" "2" "3"])
#'user/v1
user> (def v2 ["11" "3" "44"])
#'user/v2
user> (def v3 ["11" "12" "13"])
#'user/v3
user> (some (set v1) v2)
"3"
user> (some (set v1) v3)
nil
```

value `"3"` and `nil` would be considered `true` and `false` in `if` or `when`. Optionally you can explicitly wrap it with `boolean`:

```
(boolean (some (set v1) v2))
```